# Git fetch remote branch

Tags: git

A few hours ago I created a new branch on my home machine (eg. branch2), and pushed it to remote. On another machine at work, I created the same local branch, but fetching remote branch doesn't update my local repo with `git fetch`. My guess is that my local branch on other machine isn't tracked. Should I add track to my local branch, delete local branch, and checkout on remote branch?

Comment: What is the output of `git fetch`?  Keep in mind, it won't update your local branch automatically; `git pull` is generally what one uses for that.

Comment: `git fetch` simply updates the local copy with the delta from the remote.  It does not modify the working copy.  `git merge` updates the working copy from the local copy.  `git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git fetch only used to fetch the delta from the remote. If you want to fetch the remote content and want them in your working directory.

```
git fetch
```

Only fetches the delta only.

If you want to fetch the  remote contents and want the changes within your remote repository.

```
git pull = git fetch + git merge
```

Try using pit pull and the results will be in your working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebase your local branch with the remote branch.

For this just do the following::

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/your_branch
```

This should solve your problem.